# How to retrieve alt text for Image field when using Sitecore Item Web API?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-media-library

When using the Sitecore Item Web API to return an item that has an Image field the Sitecore Item Web API returns a JSON response which contains a Value which is the image tag but doesn't have any alt text. Is there a way to have the Sitecore Item Web API return the details of the referenced Media Library Item?

Example Image Field Type Response from the Sitecore Item Web API:

```
                "{7EEA5007-E518-4E68-837B-51BEAB56230A}": {
                "Name": "Image",
                "Type": "Image",
                "Value": "\u003cimage mediaid=\"{E1F8CD6F-8276-4967-983C-C37E1481CDC0}\" mediapath=\"/Images/Fragrances/Collections/M039_img4\" src=\"~/media/E1F8CD6F82764967983CC37E1481CDC0.ashx\" /\u003e"
            }
```

It appears I could parse the value for the GUID and then use Sitecore Item Web API to query the Image Item in the Media Library and retrieve the GUID but this would be messy when a parent has multiple children as I would have to request the alt tag for each separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sitecore Item Web API introduces some new pipelines declared in `Sitecore.ItemWebAPI.config`

The key pipeline you are looking for is `itemWebApiRead`.  This references the type `Sitecore.ItemWebApi.Pipelines.Read.GetResult, Sitecore.ItemWebApi` which executes the method `GetFieldInfo`.  This method actually sets the values returned for each field in the response.

As the method is `virtual` we can simply write our own class which inherits from `Sitecore.ItemWebApi.Pipelines.Read.GetResult` and implement our own `GetFieldInfo` method

#### Implementation

```
using Sitecore.Data.Fields;

namespace WebApi
{
    public class GetResult: Sitecore.ItemWebApi.Pipelines.Read.GetResult
    {
        protected override Sitecore.ItemWebApi.Dynamic GetFieldInfo(Field field)
        {
            var fieldInfo = base.GetFieldInfo(field);
            
            if (field.TypeKey == "image")
            {
                var imageField = (ImageField) field;
                fieldInfo.Add("Alt", imageField.Alt);
            }

            return fieldInfo;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, all we need to do is check the `field.TypeKey` to see if it is an image. If so, we cast to and `ImageField` and then add in the value of the `Alt` property to our `fieldInfo` object.

#### Result

```
"{4A0E7425-5927-42D6-9438-A17E875DE50A}": {
    "Name": "Image",
    "Type": "Image",
    "Value": "<image mediaid=\"{00065A73-4859-4CF3-9F51-4D01D39CAD75}\" mediapath=\"/Images/128\" src=\"~/media/00065A7348594CF39F514D01D39CAD75.ashx\" />",
    "Alt": "sitecore logo"
}
```

If you need to add further customisations for other field types you can always add a switch statement based off the `TypeKey`.

Comment: You might also want to look into the pipeline `itemWebApiGetProperties`.  This provides a pipeline to determine what properties are returned at an item level (Language, Version, DisplayName etc)